# failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10010: Read-only file system

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm not sure but is there any connection between this error and my App isnt returning location of user of some android phones, In Some android Phones its perfectly working but in lenovo k5 and other phones it isnt working and not returning location

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class LocationForAlive implements LocationListener {

    private Context context;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String mProvider;
    private String GPS = "gps";
    private String NETWORK = "network";
    private String PASSIVE = "passive";
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double arr[] = new double[2];
    private static final String TAG = "Location";

    LocationForAlive(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

        mProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        List<String> providersList = locationManager.getAllProviders();

        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        boolean isPassiveEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled || isPassiveEnabled) {
            Location location = returnLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(location == null){
                location = returnLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if(location == null){
                    location = returnLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
                    if(location == null){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        onLocationChanged(location);
                    }
                }else{
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
            }else{
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
        }
    }

    public double[] getLocation(){
        arr[0] = latitude;
        arr[1] = longitude;
        return arr;
    }

    private Location returnLocation(String providerName){

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return null;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 2000, 10, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);
        if (location != null) {
            return location;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).